# How to create a scatter plot with 4 quadrants in Spotfire

Tags: scatter-plot, spotfire

How can I create in Spotfire a scatter plot that has four quadrants, and the origin (0,0) is in the center of the visualization? I am new to Spotfire

Comment: I don't think you can. You could think of creating a calculated column that splits the two variables into 4 sector by their values, but when you trellis by this new column every trellis would have the same x axis.

Comment: You can set your min and max for each axis.

Example:

Set the x axis min to -10 and max to 10

Set the x axis min to -10 and max to 10

This will force 4 equal qudrants with 0,0 in the center.